# How to rename dataframe columns in a for in loop function

Tags: python, pandas, loops, rename

I'm kind of new to Python. I have a pandas dataframe which has about 400 columns. All columns have this structure:

```
p900_70
p901_70
p902_70
p903_70
...
```

I need to rename all these variables, so that they look like this:

```
p900_
p901_
p902_
p903_
```

As there are so many variables, I need to use a for in loop function to achieve this objective. I think it could be something like this but with a rename part inside of the loop

```
def equalize70(x):
  for i in x.columns.values:
    result = i[:-2]
    yield result
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: That was useful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('70')
```